# Proving the general solution to the wave equation in 3D is C^2

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, chain-rule, wave-equation

I'm trying to show directly by differentiation that the solution $u(x, t)$ to the 3D wave equation (as given by kirchoff's formula), for

$$\begin{cases} 
u_{tt} = c^2 \nabla u  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ (x, t) \in  \mathbb{R^3} \times [0, \infty)\\
u(x, 0) = g(x) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ x \in \mathbb{R^3} \\
u_t(x, 0) = h(x) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ x \in \mathbb{R}
\end{cases}$$
with $g \in C^3$, $h \in C^2$, is $C^2$

The strategy I was thinking to use would be to differentiate with respect to $x_i$ and $x_j$ in succession. We would start with the regular formula

$$ u(x, t) = \frac{3}{4\pi c^2t^2}\int_{\partial B(x, ct)}g(y) + \nabla g(y) \cdot (y-x) + th(y) dS_y$$

But then shift the domain of integration to the unit sphere, to avoid the dependence on $t$ in the boundary. This should give

$$ \frac{3}{4 \pi } \int_{\partial B(0, 1)}g(x + tw) + \nabla g(x+tw) \cdot (tw) + th(x + tw) dS_w.$$

The plan would be to take successive derivatives of $t$ and of $x_i$, which we can do because the integrand is a smooth function of $x$ or of $t$ on a compact set (surface of unit sphere).
However, I am unsure about the chain rule implications--I would eventually have to write down what

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \left( g(x + tw) \right)$$

is ($x$ is a vector, and so is $w$). I'm embarrassed to say, but I'm actually not sure what this partial derivative is. I am tempted to say

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \left( g(x + tw) \right)  = \nabla g(x + tw) \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}(x + tw) =  \nabla g(x + tw) \cdot \vec{e}_i = g_{x_i}(x + tw),$$

but I'm not actually sure about that. In general, I have trouble a little bit with partial derivatives of vector functions, and I don't know if I'm even doing the chain rule right here, or even if this strategy will allow me to finish the problem of showing $u(x, t)$ is $C^2$.

Comment: You were tempted to do the right thing. IDK if it helps for you to abstract it with $h(x)=x+tw$ so that $\partial_i g(x+tw) =\partial_i (g\circ h)(x) = \nabla g(h(x)) \cdot \partial_i h(x)$ but that's exactly what you did (chain rule)

Comment: We meet again! That's what I did, but I wasn't sure if the partial derivative with respect to $x_i$ of $x+ty$ really was the $i$th basis vector

Comment: hi :) That's actually because its linear, so "the derivative is constant". If it was something like $h(x)=|x+ty|^2(x+ty)$ then you'd get a mess. Also regarding the actual question at hand: its been a while since I uttered the phrase 'wave equation' but if you ignore the integral, for each $t$, and each $w$ the integrand $$g(x + tw) + \nabla g(x+tw) \cdot (tw) + th(x + tw) $$ belongs, under the given assumptions, precisely to $C^2$. So the result will follow immediately once you prove that integrating in a parameter ($w$) preserves regularity in $x$ i.e. $\partial_i \int = \int \partial_i$

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really appreciate it!